# Error passing array as Component's input

Tags: components, angular

I'm trying to pass an array to a component, as its input:

```
<history [model]="history"></history>
```

My component is:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HistoryCmp} from '../history/history';
import {Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, RouteData} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './components/home/home.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/home/home.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HomeCmp {
  history: any;
  constructor(routeData: RouteData) {
    this.history = routeData.data;//this is an array of objects: [obj1, obj2 ....]
  }
}
```

And my history component:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'history',
  templateUrl: './components/history/history.html',
  styleUrls: ['./components/history/history.css']
  //directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HistoryCmp {
  @Input() model;
  constructor() {
    //
  }
}
```

And its template:

```
<div class="history">
  <li *ngFor="#item of model">{{item.name}}</li>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't
>   a known native property ("
>       ][model]="history">
>
> "): HomeCmp@1:13

What am I doing wrong?

**edit**

Solution: I forgot to add directive dependency:

```
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HistoryCmp]
```

Thanks,
Yaniv

Comment: `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, HistoryCmp]` you missed the HistoryCmp in your HomeCmp's directives.

Comment: Cool - Just discovered this myself. Thanks!